# PHP: Can't add array to array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating new arrays and then adding these into a 'parent' array. Each of the new arrays represents a day Sunday to Saturday. Each of the days is an array itself and I am trying to preserve the name of the day as the key. This is the output I am getting at the moment (copied from Chrome):

```
array(3) {
  ["active"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["start"]=>
  int(1440219600)
  ["end"]=>
  int(1440221400)
}
array(8) {
  ["Sunday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Monday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Tuesday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Wednesday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Thursday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Friday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["Saturday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
  ["exceptional_days"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["start"]=>
    int(1440219600)
    ["end"]=>
    int(1440221400)
  }
}
```

As you can see, Sunday is NOT the key of the first array, instead it is the key of the second array. 'exceptional days' should be empty.

Here is my code:

```
$newWorkerSchedule = array();
$keys = array_keys($workerSchedule);
for($i = 0; $i < count($workerSchedule); $i++) {
    if (is_array($workerSchedule[$keys[$i]])) {
        $oldStart = $workerSchedule[$keys[$i]]['start'];
        $oldEnd = $workerSchedule[$keys[$i]]['end'];
        if($oldEnd == '00:00') {
            $oldEnd = '23:59';
        }
        $oldStart = strtotime($oldStart);
        $oldEnd = strtotime($oldEnd);
        $newStart = strtotime('+' . $timeZoneDiffHours . ' hours', $oldStart);
        $newEnd = strtotime('+' . $timeZoneDiffHours . ' hours', $oldEnd);
        $dayStart = strtotime('00:00');
        $dayEnd = strtotime('23:59');
        $timeSlotArray = array('active'=>$workerSchedule[$keys[$i]]['active'],'start'=>$newStart,'end'=>$newEnd);
        $newWorkerSchedule[$keys[$i]] = $timeSlotArray;
    }
}
```

Why is there an additional array being created at the beginning?

EDIT: As requested, the $workerSchedule array:

```
array(8) {
  ["Sunday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Monday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Tuesday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Wednesday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Thursday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Friday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["Saturday"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["active"]=>
    string(2) "no"
    ["start"]=>
    string(5) "00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(5) "00:30"
  }
  ["exceptional_days"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: share the content of `$workerSchedule`

Comment: Hi @Berriel - I actully fixed the first bit where there was an additional array being generated (I was var_dump() another array - d'oh!); however the exceptional days array at the end should still be empty.

Comment: There is something else in the code you are not showing to us. Using this `$workerSchedule`, `$newWorkerSchedule` would not have the `exceptional_days` key.

Comment: @Berriel - I updated as I pasted the wrong array in. I have now removed the 'exceptional days' array as it was in the database. When I compared to another row in the database, there's didn't have the exceptional days array and it is working fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is being created because you have it on your `$workerSchedule` array. So, you should check the results of `var_dump($workerShedule)`.

A quick way to sort it out, would be to start your loop from `i=1` instead of `i=0`.

However, you should always prefer using a simple `foreach`, it will make your code more readable, since you won't need to call `keys[$i]` all the time... eg.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Comment: Thanks @card - I tried with the foreach, but I couldn't seem to get the 'parent' key, e.g. 'Sunday', 'Monday' etc.

Comment: how did you use the foreach?
in your case, it should work:
`foreach ($workerShedule as $key => $value) $key[0]`